How to randomize the iteration of an array in Kotlin?
This is My code:
fun main() {
    var storage = arrayOf("This ", "Is ", "How ", "To ", "Create ", "Array ", "In ", "Kotlin ")
    for (elements in storage) {
        print(elements)
    }
    println()

    for (elements in storage) {
        var len = storage.size - 1
        var i = (0..len).random()
        print(storage[i])
    }
    println()
}

I want to create something like if the random() function gives a certain number it won't occur again in the loop so that every word of the array is printed.
Is there any way specificly for Kotlin or do I have to create conditions?

You could just shuffle the array and iterate over it once?

As Pawel already mentioned in the comments you can shuffle the elements in the array by calling shuffle():
storage.shuffle()
for (element in storage) {
    print(element)
}

If you want to preserve the original order for future use you can create a new shuffled list from the array:
for (element in storage.toList().shuffled()) {
    print(element)
}

Actually if you do not need to use an array, you should create a list in the first place by listOf instead of arrayOf. It uses the same array under the hood and therefore has no significant disadvantage in performance, but it is more convenient to use: You can now omit toList().
Your specific case can actually be optimized some more:
val storage = listOf("This", "Is", "How", "To", "Create", "Array", "In", "Kotlin")
val output = storage.shuffled().joinToString(" ")
println(output)

Now you do not even need the for loop anymore because this is done under the hood by joinToString. Note the parameter " ": That is the separator, so you do need the space as part of the list's elements anymore.
